# Same code for all callback implementations in Java

Tags: java, android, interface, callback, listener

I have a callback interface:

```
public interface OnServerDoneListener {

    void onDone(int code, byte[] body);

    void onFailure();
}
```

It's used as a listener for HTTP requests in many places across the app:

```
    HttpClient.getInstance().post(request, new OnServerDoneListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDone(int code, byte[] body) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure() {

        }
    });
```

Now I want to call the same code for all implementations of onFailure callback (using super, for example). And override it, if needed, for some cases. How to refactor it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an abstract class which implements the interface `OnServerDoneListener`, then define the method `onFailure` there.

```
public abstract class OnServerDoneAdapter implements OnServerDoneListener {

    public void onFailure(){
        //your defination.
    }

}
```

After that, you can pass an object (or anonymous inner class) of that class instead of the interface.

```
HttpClient.getInstance().post(request, new OnServerDoneAdapter() {        
    @Override
    public void onDone(int code, byte[] body) {

    }
});
```